# error en: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: unity2d

estoy en un proyecto para mi colegio de un juego laberinto y en el siguiente script de C#, estoy intentando crear una variable y que se ponga en true cuando colisione con la meta, pero me sale el siguiente error:

Assets\MoveCameraa.cs(8,10): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

el script es el siguiente:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MoveCameraa : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool Lvl = false; //Variable entera de la clase Counter, la cual incrementara cada que entre en colision la otra clase con el tag "Paso3"
}
namespace x
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) //aquí donde dice OnCollisionEnter2D me sale el error 
    {
        Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter2D");
        {
            if (col.collider.compareTag("Meta"))
            {
                Lvl = true;
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple y sencillamente el error es que la clase la estás definiendo fuera del namespace, por eso te dice que un namespace no puede tener directamente miembros como métodos o atributos... solo cambia el orden....

```
using UnityEngine;
namespace x {
   public class MoveCameraa : MonoBehaviour {
      public bool Lvl = false; //Variable entera de la clase Counter, la cual incrementara cada que entre en colision la otra clase con el tag "Paso3"
      void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) { //aquí donde dice OnCollisionEnter2D me sale el error 
         Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter2D");
         if (col.collider.compareTag("Meta")) {
             Lvl = true;
         }
      }    
   }   
}
```